# Sudoku - Recursive Backtracking possible-solutions-counter

Tags: java, algorithm, sudoku

I am working on a little personal Sudoku and trying to expand it.

So far I got the "Solve" part working, using a recursive backtracking method, which returns true whenever it manages to solve the recursion.

Now I am trying to build a unique solution board generator, and I've found quite a bit of info online about how it can be implemented.

However, I am struggling on the first step, which is my boolean recursive backtracking algorithm into a recursive algorithm that keeps a count of a possible solutions. This is essential to check whether my generated board is unique.

On a larger note, I've realized that I've struggled with this problem before when implementing some recursive sorts: How to transform a boolean recursive function into a recursive function that returns some kind of count (int/long), without losing the functionality? Is there any sort of guidelines or technique to follow?

Attached is the working code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sudoku {

    int[][] board;

    public Sudoku(){}

    public Sudoku(int n){
        this.board=new int[n][n];
    }

    /* Creates an NxN game.board in a two-dimensional array*/
    public static int[][] createBoard(int n)
    {
        int[][] board = new int[n][n];
        for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<board[i].length; j++)
                board[i][j]=0;
        return board;
    }

    /* prints the game.board*/
    public static void printBoard(int[][] b)
    {
        int buffer=(int)Math.sqrt(b.length);
        // fitting the bottom line into any size of game.board
        String btm=new String(new char[buffer*buffer*3+buffer+1]).replace("\0", "_");

        for (int i=0; i<b.length; i++)
        {
            if (i%buffer==0)
                System.out.println(btm);
            for (int j=0; j<b[i].length; j++)
            {
                if (j%buffer==0)
                    System.out.print("|");
                if (b[i][j]==0)
                    System.out.print(" _ ");
                else
                    System.out.print(" " + b[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }
        System.out.println(btm);
    }

    /* returns true if a number can be inserted in a row, otherwise returns false. */
    public static boolean checkLegalRow(int[][] b, int row, int num)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<b.length; i++)
        {
            if (b[row][i]==num)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    /* returns true if a number can be inserted in a column, otherwise returns false.*/
    public static boolean checkLegalCol(int[][] b, int col, int num)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<b.length; i++)
        {
            if (b[i][col]==num)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*returns true if number can be inserted in its local box.*/
    public static boolean checkLegalBox(int[][] b, int row, int col, int num)
    {
        int buffer=(int)Math.sqrt(b.length);
        for (int i=0, adjRow=row-(row%buffer); i<buffer; i++, adjRow++)
        {
            for (int j=0, adjCol=col-(col%buffer); j<buffer; j++, adjCol++)
            {
                if (b[adjRow][adjCol]==num)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*allows user input for a sudoku game.board*/
    public static void fillInBoardConsole(int[][] b)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a row: ");
        int r=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter a column: ");
        int c=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter a number from 1 to "+b.length+": ");
        int num=sc.nextInt();
        while (num>b.length || num<1)
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number from 1 to "+b.length+": ");
            num=sc.nextInt();
        }
        b[r][c]=num;
        sc.close();
    }

    /* returns true if all the conditions for sudoku legal move are met: there is no 
 * number on the same row, column, box, and the cell isn't taken*/
    public static boolean legalMove(int[][] b, int row, int col, int num)
    {
        return checkLegalRow(b,row,num) && checkLegalCol(b,col,num) && checkLegalBox(b,row,col,num) && b[row][col]==0;
    }

    /* returns true if the initial board setting is legal*/
    public static boolean initialLegal(int[][] b)
    {
        int num;
        for (int i=0; i<b.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<b[i].length; j++)
            {
                if (b[i][j]!=0)
                {
                    num=b[i][j];
                    b[i][j]=0;
                    if (!(checkLegalRow(b,i,num) && checkLegalCol(b,j,num) && checkLegalBox(b,i,j,num)))
                    {
                        b[i][j]=num;
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                        b[i][j]=num;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /* using backtrack algorithm and recursion to solve the sudoku*/
    public static boolean solveBacktrack(int[][] b, int row, int col)
    { 
        /*If the cell is already taken by a number:
         * case 1: if its the last cell (rightmost, lowest) is already taken, sudoku solved
         * case 2: if its the rightmost cell not on the if it is the rightmost column but not 
         * the lowest row, go to the leftmost cell in next row
         * case 3: if it's a regular cell, go for the next cell*/
        if (b[row][col]!=0)
        {
            if (col==b.length-1) 
                if (row==b.length-1)
                {
                    //printgame.board(b); // case 1
                    return true; 
                }
                else 
                    return solveBacktrack(b,row+1,0); // case 2
            else
                return solveBacktrack(b,row,col+1); // case 3
        }

        boolean solved=false;

        for (int k=1; k<=b.length; k++) //iterates through all numbers from 1 to N
        {
            // If a certain number is a legal for a cell - use it
            if (legalMove(b,row,col,k)) 
            {
                b[row][col]=k;
                if (col==b.length-1) // if it's the rightmost column
                {
                    if (row==b.length-1) // and the lowest row - the sudoku is solved
                    {
                        //printgame.board(b);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                        solved=solveBacktrack(b,row+1,0); // if its not the lowest row - keep solving for next row
                }
                else // keep solving for the next cell
                    solved=solveBacktrack(b,row,col+1);
            }
            if (solved)
                return true;
            else //if down the recursion sudoku isn't solved-> remove the number (backtrack)
            {
                b[row][col]=0;
            }
        }
        return solved;
    }

    /*  public static long solveCountSolutions(int[][]b, int row, int col, long counter)
    {   

    }
     */ 


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Sudoku game = new Sudoku(9);
        game.board[0][2]=5;game.board[0][1]=3; game.board[0][0]=1;
        game.board[8][2]=4;game.board[8][4]=3;game.board[8][6]=6;
        printBoard(game.board);
        if (initialLegal(game.board))
            System.out.println(solveBacktrack(game.board,0,0));
        else
            System.out.println("Illegal setting");
        printBoard(game.board);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to check if the sudoku is really a sudoku (has a unique solution per definition), then there is a simple trick: 1. solve from bottom (try 1,2,3,... first), 2. solve from top (try 9, 8, 7, ... first), 3. if the two solutions match then the sudoku has only one unique solution.

Comment: Interesting! just to clarify, should I start from the same cell (top left in my case), and the only change should be the numbers I'm trying to insert into the grid?

Comment: Yes exactly. If you want to count the solutions, then you need a counter and don't stop solving when you found a solution, instead increment the counter.

Comment: A very basic approach would be to have an variable of type `int` of larger scope, don't terminate upon returning `true` and increment the variable whenever `true` is returned.

Comment: @maraca thanks! will try to implement it.
The rest - I am not asking for an actual code, it is more important to me to understand how to work around these problems. I've tried couple of times to write a function that returns 0 for false and 1 for true, but somehow through the recursion stack it lost it. Another problem was to re-write the function solveBacktrack not to terminate once a True solution was found.
I didn't try using a global variable, though.

Answer (score 0):

Such a function could be implemented by not exiting from the recursion when a solution is found, but instead dump that solution to an external structure (if you only need counts, make a counter somewhere outside of the function but visible to it, and increment it once a solution is found), and then continue searching like if you've hit a dead end. Something in line of this (abstract code):

```
static int solutions=0;
bool recursiveSolver(TYPE data) {
    TYPE newData;
    while (!nextChoice(data)) {
        if (solved(data)) {
            // return true; not now, we count instead
            solutions++;
        }
        newData=applyNextChoice(data); // for recursion
        if (recursiveSolver(newData)) { 
           return true; // will never hit, but checking is needed for solver to work
        }
    } 
    // all choices checked, no solution
    return false;
}
```

`applyNextChoice()` is a placeholder for "select next number, put into this cell" in case of sudoku. `TYPE` is a placeholder for whatever structure that represents an incomplete solution, in your case a combined `int[][] b, int row, int col`.